# Flask: Not able to receive HTML form POST data

Tags: html, forms, post, twitter-bootstrap, flask

Here is my HTML

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" action="/" method="POST">
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign In</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

When I submit form, on server I try to print it, I do

```
   def post(self):
        print 'data :', request.form
```

I get

```
data : ImmutableMultiDict([])
```

I also try

```
def post(self):
        print 'data :', request.json
```

I get

```
data : None
```

What exactly I am missing here

Answer (score 11, accepted):

None of your inputs have name attribute

Therefore, nothing sent.

```
        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
```

should be:

```
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
```

ID is just for DOM