# Can't get any POST from html form

Tags: python, flask

I've a problem where i can't get `POST` from `html`
**Log:**

```
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Apr/2021 00:51:25] "←[37mGET /main?user=adasd&pass=123123 HTTP/1.1←[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Apr/2021 00:51:25] "←[36mGET /static/css/index.css HTTP/1.1←[0m" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Apr/2021 00:51:25] "←[36mGET /static/js/index.js HTTP/1.1←[0m" 304 -
```

I've searched on `stackoverflow`&`google` , but still not coming to a solution ,
[Flask receiving no data for HTML POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161078/flask-receiving-no-data-for-html-post)
[Flask: Not able to receive HTML form POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16160528/flask-not-able-to-receive-html-form-post-data)
[Flask: Tutorial for MySql , just take a look on POST in html](https://www.askpython.com/python-modules/flask/flask-mysql-database)

**index.html**

```
...
<form action="{{url_for('enter')}}" methods="POST" autocomplete="off">
        <p>Username:</p><input type="text" name='user'><br>
        <p>Password:</p><input type="password" name='pass'><br><br><br>
        <input type='submit' value='Enter'>
        <input type='button' onclick="location.href='{{url_for('register')}}'" value='Register Here'>
    </form>
...
```

**main.py**

```
@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/main",methods=["POST","GET"])
def enter():
    app.logger.info("main "+request.method) # return GET
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form.get("user")
        password = request.form.get("pass")
        app.logger.info(username) # returns None
        app.logger.info(password) # returns None
        return render_template('enter.html')
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,host='localhost', port=5000)
```

**How i run my code**
*on Powershell* `python main.py`
Note:`ImmutableMultiDict([])`

Answer (score 0):

Your input type fields are lacking the **value** attribute. That's why your are not receiving input.

Comment: but the value for the `<input` is by user

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution 
[Way to make input make a POST in form](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_formmethod.asp)

use `formmethod` 
e.g.`<input formmethod="post" type="submit" value="enter">`